# Enlaces externos rotos wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

He analizado mi pagina web mediante Semrush y brokenlinkcheck.com y me indica que tengo varios enlaces externos rotos.

Los enlaces me llevan a crear una cuenta en la plantilla del tema astra que utilice al principio para diseñar la pagina, donde fui borrando varias cosas, entre ellas un botón que había en el encabezado, el cual contiene la misma url.

Cada vez que creo una pagina es un nuevo enlace roto, ya que se encuentra en la parte del encabezado y no se como eliminarlo.

Si alguien me podría ayudar se lo agradecería, muchas gracias.[código error]

Este es un ejemplo de uno de los codigos que me indica brokenlinkcheck.com que provoca el fallo, pero como este hay como 18 más.

```
<div class="ast-header-account-wrap">
<a class="ast-header-account-link ast-header-account-type-icon ast-account-action-link" aria-label="Enlace del icono de la cuenta" href=https://websitedemos.net/brandstore-08/wp-login.php target=_self  >
<span class="ahfb-svg-iconset ast-inline-flex svg-baseline"><svg version='1.1' class='account-icon' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 120 120' enable-background='new 0 0 120 120' xml:space='preserve'><path d='M84.6,62c-14.1,12.3-35.1,12.3-49.2,0C16.1,71.4,3.8,91,3.8,112.5c0,2.1,1.7,3.8,3.8,3.8h105c2.1,0,3.8-1.7,3.8-3.8 C116.2,91,103.9,71.4,84.6,62z'/><circle cx='60' cy='33.8' r='30'/></svg></span></a></div>
```

Comment: Sin un ejemplo no podremos ayudarte amigo.

Comment: Acabo de añadir un ejemplo, por si me puedes ayudar, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes eliminar el codigo que este llamando a ese boton o este creando el boton. Debes localizar el tema que estas usando, luego donde almacenas el sitio busca la carpeta **wp-content** dentro del directorio vas a **themes** y en la carpeta de tu tema probablemente sea en el archivo head.php header.php o puede que tenga otro nombre.